# How do I use the public variables and methods in this class?

Tags: java, swing, methods, jpanel, awt

The following code creates 12 panels with a label and a button on each panel.

```
public MainFormWithPanel() {
    InventoryFileReader reader = new InventoryFileReader();
    ArrayList<Car> cars = reader.getAllCars();

    setLayout(new GridLayout(0,4));//set rows to zero so it fills rows first

    for(int i = 0; i < cars.size(); i++){
    InventoryItemPanel panel = new InventoryItemPanel();
    panel.setLabel(cars.get(i).getYear(), cars.get(i).getMake(), 
           cars.get(i).getModel(),cars.get(i).getMiles(), cars.get(i).getPrice());
    add(panel);
    }

    pack();

    initComponents();
}
```

This following class holds the setLabel method that I am using above, but it does not return the values that I am passing from the cars.

```
public class InventoryItemPanel extends JPanel{
public int year;
public String make;
public String model;
public int miles;
public int price;



JLabel label = setLabel(year, make, model, miles, price);
Button button = new Button("View More Details");

public InventoryItemPanel(){
    setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
    add(label);
    add(button);


}

public JLabel setLabel(int year, String make, String model, int miles, int price){
    Locale locale = new Locale("en", "US");
    NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale);     
    return new JLabel("<html>"+ year + " " + make + 
                " " + model + "<br> " +  + miles
                + " miles" + "<br>" +  formatter.format(price)+"</html>");
}
}
```

The output for the code is:

```
0 null null
0 miles
$0.00
```

When the real output should be:

```
2012 Toyota Corolla

70000 Miles

$12,000.00
```

How am I supposed to implement the setLabel method from InventoryItemPanel class in the MainFormWithPanel class?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the [edit] link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: You just put up fractions of your code. My recommendation: don't work with 12 panels. Work with **one** panel, in an example frame. Then think about "duplicating" it. (if you had just **one** piece of code, you could also give it to us much easier). Make sure you get that to work. Why do you folks always think "hmm, juggling is hard, so lets start practicing with 5 balls ... instead of say 1 or 2"?!

Comment: I'll try to see if I can shorten it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try modifying the line:

```
    add(panel);
```

in `MainFormWithPanel` to:

```
    add(panel.setLabel(cars.get(i).getYear(), cars.get(i).getMake(), 
       cars.get(i).getModel(),cars.get(i).getMiles(), cars.get(i).getPrice()));
```

Comment: Got an incompatible types error, but it was worth a shot anyway, Thanks.

Comment: Ahh yes, because panel is InventoryItemPanel not JLabel. I've edited the answer above. It should work as long as your add method can take JLabel as an argument.

Comment: Ace! Instance variables won't store anything so once you've triggered them they sort of vanish unless you do something with them directly. Please set to accept as answer and upvote :)